# proper response when allowing multiple origins

Tags: cors

I need to allow multiple origins, and for that I match the origin received in the `Origin` HTTP header against a regular expression.

If the `Origin` header matches then I send its value back with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

What should happen if `Origin` does not match?

If I had a single allowed domain then I would respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to this allowed domain, but since I support several domains I am not sure whether I should omit the CORS headers altogether or respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respond without a CORS header. That is sufficient to indicate to the downstream client that CORS is not allowed from the origin. Also `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null` has some semantic meaning, because `Origin: null` can be a valid value (this is usually used when a request is made from an HTML file rather than a web server).